# Facing problem while using integer array C++

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error on the 11th line, but if I use `char candidate_id[30]` then there is no error. Even if I write `int candidate _id` there is still no error:

```
Error is:11 6   C:\Users\SOUVIK\Desktop\gym 1.cpp   [Error] no match for  
 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and
'int [30]')
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class gym
{
public:
  int    candidate_id[30];
  char   candidate_name[30];
  float  candidate_age;

  void  accept()
  {
    cout << "ID:";
    cin >> candidate_id;
    cout << "Name:";
    cin >> candidate_name;
    cout << "Age";
    cin >> candidate_age;
  }

  void  display()
  {
    cout << "ID:" << candidate_id << endl;
    cout << "Name:" << candidate_name << endl;
    cout << "Age:" << candidate_age << endl;
  }
};

int  main()
{
  gym  obj[30];

  obj[30].accept();
  obj[30].display();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ provides no standard way to read arrays from `cin` (except for `char []`).  Should `candidate_id` really be an array? If yes, you need to read all the elements by hand.

Comment: Sidenote: `obj[30].accept();` causes undefined behaviour, because it's an out-of-bounds-access. Array inidices in C++ start at 0, thus the last valid index is length - 1 (29 in this case).

Comment: @churill Actually for 30 candidates there will be 30 different IDs and that is the reason I have considered candidate_id as an array.

Comment: _Each_ instance of `gym` contains an array of 30, which brings us to 900 IDs in total (30 instances, with each 30 IDs)

Comment: You can't fill up the array directly like that, you need a loop with an index and each time do ```cin >> candidate_id[i];```

Answer (score 1):

You have two concepts in your code, a gym and a candidate, and it seems you are confused about how to handle these. You writen a class called `gym` but the fields you've added to this class are all about a candidate (name, age, id etc). Then in `main` you've declared an array of `gym`. Do you really want a program that deals with 30 gyms? Or is your program about a single gym which can have 30 candidates?

I'm going to assume the latter. In that case you need to declare a class called `candidate` (not `gym`) and put everything in that class that is needed for a single candidate.

What you need to do is define a class for a single candidate, let's call it Candidate.

```
// A candidate for the gym
class Candidate
{
  int candidate_id;
  char candidate_name[30];
  float candidate_age;
  ...
};
```

Then in `main`, you can declare your gym variable which is an array of thirty candidates

```
int main()
{
   Candidate gym[30];
   ...
}
```

That's the basic *design*. If you're happy with that then you can start writing the rest of the code. But don't change the design just as a quick way to 'solve' compiler errors. If the design is right then you have to solve compiler errors without changing the design.

Of course if the design is wrong then you change it, but think about the design first.

The obvious enhancement to this design would be to add a gym class. That gym class would then (presumably) contain an array for the thirty candidates.

```
class Candidate
{
    ...
};

class Gym
{
    Candidate candidates[30];
    ...
};

int main()
{
    Gym gym;
    ...
}
```

If you think that design makes more sense then go for it. Just remember design first, then code.